# how to enlarge figures in latex /overleaf

Tags: minipage

I have tried this code to print 3 figures in a row in IEEE format. However, the figures have a lot of space between one another .. and the figures are too small ho can I enlarge the figures and reduce the space between them

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{aaa.png}%
    \caption{aaa}%
    \label{Fig9:aaa}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{aa.png}%
    \label{Fig10:aa}
    \caption{aaa}%
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{aa.png}%
    \caption{aa}%
    \label{Fig11:aa}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use  `\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}`

Comment: (see, you get exactly what you ask TeX to do. It's recommended to understand what the code does before copying it in.)